# Can I recover my disappeared Sticky Note gadget after a crash?

Tags: sticky-notes

My computer crashed and my son fixed it but the sticky note gadget disappeared from the taskbar.  And we can't find it anywhere.  I need it because it is a very helpful gadget.  How can I install it back?

Comment: What operating system are you running? Vista or 7?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that your using Windows 7 (this solution should work for Vista, except for the pinning to the start menu) and that it hasn't actually been un-installed just removed from the task bar. To open it again open the Start menu and type "sticky" (without quotes) and it should be the first item shown.

If you then want it to stay in the task bar (even when closed). Right-click on the Stick Note icon and select "Pin this program to start bar".

Comment: Are Sticky Notes part of Windows 7 or Office 2010? Always assumed they where part of Office 2010 but i might be wrong! :)

Comment: I'm reasonably sure they are Windows